# Pass a Cocoa NSArray to an Applescript list

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript

I have an app that runs an applescript.  One of the requirements is to take an array created in Objective-C and pass it to Applescript as a list.

I have code that allows me to run an applescript with variables so I can pass vars successfully but I haven't figured out arrays.

Anyhow, I have the NSArray and I don't know how to have Applescript make it useable.  I can pass variables to Applescript but I don't know how to send the array so it's usable.

How would I get an Obj-C NSArray like this:

```
NSMutableArray *myColors;
myColors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", @"Yellow", nil];
```

into an Applescript list like this:

```
set colorList to {"Red","Green","Blue"} as list
```

I've tried this to no avail

```
set colorList to myColors as list
```

This is how the vars are passed to applescript FYI

```
#import "Utils.h"

@implementation Utils

+ (NSArray *)arrayFromDescriptor:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)descriptor {
    // Enumerate the apple descriptors (lists) returned by the applescript and
    // make them into arrays
    NSMutableArray *returnArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSInteger counter, count = [descriptor numberOfItems];

    for (counter = 1; counter <= count; counter++) {
        NSAppleEventDescriptor *desc = [descriptor descriptorAtIndex:counter];
        if (nil != [desc descriptorAtIndex:1]) {
            [returnArray addObject:[Utils arrayFromDescriptor:desc]];
        } else {
            NSString *stringValue = [[descriptor descriptorAtIndex:counter] stringValue];
            if (nil != stringValue) {
                [returnArray addObject:stringValue];
            } else {
                [returnArray addObject:@""];
            }
        }
    }
    return returnArray;
}
+ (NSString *)escapeCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    return [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
}

+ (NSArray *)runApplescript:(NSString *)source withVariables:(NSDictionary *)variables {
    NSString *input = @"";
    NSArray *variableNames = [variables allKeys];
    // Transform the dictionary of names/values to set sentences of applescript
    for (NSString *variableName in variableNames) {
        NSObject *variableValue = [variables objectForKey:variableName];
        if ([variableValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            input =
                [input stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"set %@ to (\"%@\" as text)\n", variableName,
                                                                          [Utils escapeCharacters:variableValue], nil]];
        } else if ([variableValue isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            input = [input stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"set %@ to (%@ as integer)\n",
                                                                              variableName, variableValue, nil]];
        } else if ([variableValue isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            // Initialize a list
            NSString *entry;
            NSArray *values = (NSArray *)variableValue;
            input = [input stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"set %@ to {", variableName]];
            BOOL first = TRUE;
            for (entry in values) {
                if (!first) {
                    input = [input stringByAppendingString:@", "];
                }
                input = [input
                    stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", [Utils escapeCharacters:entry], nil]];

                first = FALSE;
            }
            input = [input stringByAppendingString:@"}\n"];
        }
    }
    NSString *finalScript = [input stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n%@", source]];
    NSLog(@"Final script: %@", finalScript);
    NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:finalScript];
    NSDictionary *error;
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *descriptor = [script executeAndReturnError:&error];
    NSLog(@"applescript error: %@", [error description]);
    // Transform the return value of applescript to nested nsarrays
    return [Utils arrayFromDescriptor:descriptor];
}
+ (NSArray *)runApplescriptFromFile:(NSString *)scriptName withVariables:(NSDictionary *)variables {
    NSString *scriptPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:scriptName ofType:@"applescript"];
    NSString *scriptSource =
        [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:scriptPath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
    return [Utils runApplescript:scriptSource withVariables:variables];
}
+ (BOOL)stringIsEmptyOrWhite:(NSString *)string {
    string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    return [string isEqualToString:@""];
}

@end
```

And then call this from my code:

```
[Utils runApplescript:scriptSource withVariables:variables];
```

Comment: How do you pass the ObjC array to AppleScript?

Comment: You are mixing apples with oranges. If you are going run call `runAppleScript` you cannot _pass_ anything; you simply construct the script as a string and run it. The _right_ way to do this, however, is to construct an NSAppleScript object. (@vadian correct me if I'm wrong; it's been so long since I've done this that I've forgotten a lot.)

Comment: Do you want to pass the variables to the script or do you want to set the variables in the script source? Is `finalScript` ok, does it work in Script Editor? Can you give an example of the value of `variables`? I tried your code and an array works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Now, AppleScript use Cocoa-Scripting Bridge. After macOS 10.10, you can use Cocoa function in AppleScript.

If you make Cocoa framework with your Objective-C program, you can call custom cocoa framework. The Objective-C program returns NSArray, then the value is coerced into AppleScript list.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/ScriptingAutomation/RN-AppleScriptObjC/index.html

I made BayesKit.framework from Bayes program on Github, and call it from AppleScript. BayesKit returns NSDictionary and the result is corerced into AppleScript record.

http://piyocast.com/as/archives/4756